# How to mock @select in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs

When talking about testing in Angular, many approaches can be found on google, stackoverflow, etc. I followed [this](https://www.capgemini.com/2017/11/unit-and-integration-testing-in-angular/) instruction here to clearly differ between unit tests and integration tests. Writing unit tests without TestBed works very good until I had to mock an @select property for getting data from the redux store. I cannot directly assign an Observable to the @select property. Is there any way to mock it without using TestBed? I only want to test the pure functions of my components and not the store, services or other dependencies. Therefore I don't use TestBed and instanciate the component object itself instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's more work for you, but I'd move your `@select()`s to a service. That way you can mock the entire service in your component tests, and keep your components from being too tightly coupled to your redux store.

For example, instead of:

```
class MyComponent {
  ...
  @select(someSelector) someString: Observable<string>;
  ...
}
```

do:

```
class MyStoreService {
  ...
  @select(someSelector) someString: Observable<string>;
  ...
}

class MyComponent {
  ...
  constructor(storeService: MyStoreService) {}
  ...
  doSomething(): Observable<string> {
    return this.storeService.someString;
  }
  ...
}
```